# How to find radius of circle through similar triangles?

Tags: triangles

[image]

If PR $= 15$cm and AC $= 5$cm, use similar triangles to find the radius of the circle.

I understand how to do similar triangles,but an unsure of how to find the appropriate lengths in order to find the radius. I tried to use my triangle rules to no avail. How would I go about solving this? Thanks a lot

Comment: The drawing is a bit misleading because C should be lower than that on the circumference of the circle.

Comment: Just to be clear: is $AB$ a diameter of the circle?

Comment: @TobyMak, yes it is

Comment: According to [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/ja79dcxv) the radius is around $5.04$.

Comment: Is Q the centre of the circle? If not then I'm surprised there aren't infinite solutions.

Comment: Maybe it's an O (for origin) with a small dash, not a Q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the angle ACB is a right angle by Thales theorem. Second, the angle QPA is the same as the angle labeled x (parallel lines) which is the same as the angle CBA (sum of angles of the triangle ABC is $180°$). Hence the triangles PQA and ABC are similar and we have $$\frac{AB}{AC}=\frac{PQ}{AQ}$$ Now let $r$ denote the radius of the circle, then this is equivalent to $$\frac{2r}{5}=\frac{15-r}{r}$$
This is a quadratic equation, only the solution $$r=-\frac{5}{4}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^2+\frac{75}{2}}$$ is positive.

Edit: as remarked by Toby Mak, this simplifies to $r=5$.

Edit 2: I assumed that Q is the center of the circle. I don't think there is a unique solution otherwise.

Comment: ... which is basically $r=5$.

Comment: Alternatively $2r^2 = 75 - 5r \Rightarrow 2r^2+5r-75 = 0 \Rightarrow (r-5)(2r+15) = 0$ which leads to $r=5$.

Comment: @TobyMak Sure, I just looked at the equation, recognized a quadratic and thought, general solution exists, done.

Comment: I just want to point out, that in your answer you assume that $Q$ is the origin, right?